# Hallows are found between 2 regions

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I am trying to use LASSO to make a prediction by female genomes. I plotted a height histogram. The result shows as below. [image]

Regression requires data to be normal. The shape of the histogram looks like a normal distribution if those hollows between two peaks are not that deep. I am wondering what causes this. It doesn't make sense that height frequency between 164 and 165 is 100, and height frequency between 165 to 166 is less than 40, but the height frequency between 168 to 169 goes back to almost 100. Does it indicate we need more data ? or Is there any plausible reasons cause that ? Is there any good techniques that can make this dataset more normal ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The errors from fitting should be normally distributed, but not necessarily the data itself. As an example, consider fitting data to an exponential function.